# Assign function stored in variable as getter in object literal

Tags: javascript

Say I have a function. If I wanted to add it as a method to an object, I would use:

```
let foofunc = function() {}
{
  foo: foofunc
}
```

However, what if I want to add it as a getter? You'd think I could do it like this:

```
{
  get x: foofunc
}
```

but my IDE complains, so I assume that's not possible. How would I do this?

Comment: *Say I have a function. If I wanted to add it as a method to an object, I would use"* What you've shown would only work if you had `x = ` or similar before the `{` on the second line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Object.defineProperty` function like so:

```
function getterFunc() { return 1; }
let anObject = {};
Object.defineProperty(anObject, 'propertyName', {get: getterFunc});
```

Live Example:

```js
function getterFunc() { return 1; }
let anObject = {};
Object.defineProperty(anObject, 'propertyName', {get: getterFunc});
console.log(anObject.propertyName); // 1
```

You can access use the getter normally by doing `anObject.propertyName`.
The [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) has more detailed information if you still have more questions.

Answer (score -1):

To make it as getter function..

```
let foofunc = function() { return this.x;}

let obj = {
  x: "marvel",
  get foo(){return foofunc.call(this)}
};
```

use:

```
console.log(obj.foo);
```